# Unity3d SelectionGrid cell size adjustment

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I try to create game options but got problem with cell size adjustment.
For option "First move" I use names of users. I want to increase cell if name is too long. Or decrease font size if it easier.
 [image]

Style for cells:

```
    mCellStyle = new GUIStyle();//style for cells
    mCellStyle.normal.background = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/button_up_9patch");
    mCellStyle.onNormal.background = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/button_down_9patch");
    mCellStyle.focused.background = mButtonStyle.active.background;
    mCellStyle.fontSize = GUIUtils.GetKegel() - GUIUtils.GetKegel() / 5;
    mCellStyle.border = new RectOffset(7, 7, 7, 7);
    mCellStyle.padding = new RectOffset(20, 20, 20, 20);
    mCellStyle.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
    mCellStyle.wordWrap = true;
```

My code:

```
    GUIStyle lBackStyle = new GUIStyle(mCellStyle);
    lBackStyle.fontSize = GUIUtils.GetKegel();
    lBackStyle.active.background = null;
    lBackStyle.focused.background = null;

    GUIStyle lStyle = new GUIStyle(lBackStyle);
    lStyle.normal.background = null;

    //create contents and calculate height
    GUIContent lContent1 = new GUIContent(LanguageManager.GetText("FirstMove"));
    float lElemH1 = lStyle.CalcHeight(lContent1, lMaxWidht);
    GUIContent[] lArrayContent2 = new GUIContent[] { new GUIContent(MainScript.Logic.UserName), new GUIContent(MainScript.Logic.NurslingName) };
    float lElemH2 = mCellStyle.CalcHeight(lArrayContent2[0], lMaxWidht);
    GUIContent lContent3 = new GUIContent(LanguageManager.GetText("Difficulty"));
    float lElemH3 = lStyle.CalcHeight(lContent3, lMaxWidht);
    GUIContent[] lArrayContent4 = new GUIContent[] { new GUIContent(LanguageManager.GetText("Easy")), new GUIContent(LanguageManager.GetText("Hard")) };
    float lElemH4 = mCellStyle.CalcHeight(lArrayContent4[0], lMaxWidht);

    float lTotalH = lElemH1 + lElemH2 + lElemH3 /*+ 100*/;//reserve 100 for paddings

    GUILayout.BeginArea(mAreaRect);
    GUILayout.BeginVertical(lBackStyle, GUILayout.Height(lTotalH));
    GUILayout.Label(lContent1, lStyle);
    GamePreferences.setAIMakesFirstMove(GUILayout.SelectionGrid(GamePreferences.getAIMakesFirstMove(), lArrayContent2, 2, mCellStyle));
    GUILayout.Label(lContent3, lStyle);
    GamePreferences.setDifficulty(GUILayout.SelectionGrid(GamePreferences.getDifficulty(), lArrayContent4, 2, mCellStyle));
    GUILayout.EndVertical();
    GUILayout.EndArea();
```

ADDED: I just want to set height of cell in Selection Grid. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found that I can pass `GUILayoutOption` as last parameter to set the height of cells:

```
GUILayout.SelectionGrid(GamePreferences.getFirstMove(), lArrayContent2, 2, mCellStyle, GUILayout.Height(lCellHeight))
```

But I still have no idea how I can fit cell size to it content.

```
float lElemH2 = mCellStyle.CalcHeight(lArrayContent2[0], lMaxWidht);
```

`mCellStyle.CalcHeight` ignores lenght of content and in `lElemH2` I got height for single line text.

**EDITED:**
My fault, I sent wrong parameters to CalcHeight. Correct version:

`float lElemH2 = mCellStyle.CalcHeight(lArrayContent2[0], lMaxWidht / cellsCount);`